# runtime error in bundle adjustment example - matlab

Tags: matlab, bundle, matlab-cvst, adjustment

I asked it in MATLAB forums but didnt get a response. Hoping someone can answer the question here:

I tried using Bundle Adjustment example at https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/bundleadjustment.html#inputarg_xyzPoints

However, I get an error: "Error using getPrmDflt (line 47) odd number of parameters in prm Error in bundleAdjustment (line 49) getPrmDflt( varargin,{ 'KMask', [], 'nItr', 500, ..."

at this line: [xyzRefinedPoints,refinedPoses] = bundleAdjustment(xyzPoints,pointTracks,cameraPoses,cameraParams);

After looking more into it the input to getPrmDflt is totally different that what the function expects. Is there some bug or wrong function call in bundle adjustment code?

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in MathWorks code it would probably be better to contact technical support for help: https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was an error from my side. I had downloaded Vincent's MATLAB toolbox a couple of years ago for use and it had a bundleAdjustment function call that overrode the MATLAB function.